# búsqueda no muestra lista LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, lista, select

les explico, tengo un SELECT que me muestra los cursos y al apretar "BUSCAR" me debe mostrar los alumnos que están en ese curso ojala que me muestre en forma de label los nombre y DNI de los alumnos, y al lado de cada alumno, me de la opcion (con otro select) de colocarlo ausente y presente, el tema es que no me esta mostrando la lista que quiero, ayúdenme por favor, adjunto el codigo

HTML

```html
<div class="card-body">
<!--BUSQUEDA-->
  <form method="get" class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('asistencia.buscar')}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="listCursos" name="listCursos" required>
          @foreach ($listCursosA as $listadoCurso)
          <option value="{{ $listadoCurso['id'] }}">{{$listadoCurso['nombre'] }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button>Buscar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
<!--./ busqueda-->
  <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('asistencia.store') }}" role="form">
    @csrf
    <!--aqui deberia mostrarla lista (no he agregado aun el select que me diria si el alumno esta presente o ausente)-->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label name="alumnos_curso" id="alumnos_curso"></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button>Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```js
public function buscar(Request $request) {
  $clase = $request->listCursos;

  if ($request->get('busqueda')) {
    $usuarios = User::where('id_curso', '=', $clase)->get();
  }
  return view('asistencia.create') - > with('Asistencia.create', $usuarios);
}
```

ROUTE

```js
Route::get('asistencia/buscar','asistenciaController@buscar')->name('asistencia.buscar');
```

Y ME MUESTRA ESTO AL APRETAR BUSCAR
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si pruebas con `$clase = $request->Input('listCursos');` ya que estas pasando directo desde el formulario, mejor ponlo `post` y en ningun momento pasas `busqueda` como parametro, asi es que se salta el listado

Comment: como tendria que ser entonces amigo?

Comment: hice lo que me dijiste, ahora me trae los datos, el problema es que nose como hacerlo para que me los muestre en la pagina ya que lo visualize como dd('variable'); pero ahora nose como mostrarlo en la pagina

Comment: prueba con `return view('asistencia.create',compact('usuarios '))` con eso pasas usuarios a la vista, si quieres ver que llega pon en la vista `{{$usuarios }}`, aunque inicialmente creo que te saldra error ya que `asistencia.create` no tiene dicho parámetro

Comment: exactamente me sale error por ese parametro

Comment: intena con esto return view('asistencia.create',['usuarios '=>$usuarios ]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intena con esto

```
return view('asistencia.create',['usuarios'=>$usuarios ]);
```

y en la vista haces esto

```
@if(isset($usuarios) && $usuarios->isNotEmpty())
   @foreach($usuarios as $user) 
      {{$user->dni}} - {{$user->name}}
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo en responder, por favor considera agregar una explicación a tu respuesta de modo que los demás sepamos que modificaste y como este script soluciona el problema planteado

Comment: excelente, gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio eso!